# Heaps algorithm in swift

Tags: swift, heaps-algorithm

I have an implementation of Heap's algorithm in Swift that I am trying to convert to NOT use inout parameters.

However I get different results for each (the second is wrong, delivering a repeated permutation). What is going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Original implementation:

```
func permutations(_ n:Int, _ a: inout Array<Character>) {
    if n == 1 {print(String(a)); return}
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        permutations(n-1,&a)
        a.swapAt(n-1, (n%2 == 1) ? 0 : i)
    }
    permutations(n-1,&a)
}
var arr = Array("ABC".characters)
permutations(arr.count,&arr)
```

> Output: ABC BAC CAB ACB BCA CBA

Implementation without inout parameters:

```
func permutations (_ n: Int, _ a: Array<Character>) {
    var ary = a
    if (n == 1){
        print(String(ary));
        return
    }
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        permutations(n-1, ary)
        ary.swapAt(n-1, (n%2 == 1) ? 0 : i)
    }
    permutations(n-1, ary)
}
var arr = Array("ABC".characters)
permutations(arr.count,arr)
```

output:

> Output: ABC BAC CBA BCA ABC BAC

Note we don't get CAB in this output, and also have a repetition of "BAC" and "ABC".

I can't quite see how the two are not equivalent, and want to create a version of this algorithm without the inout parameter.

Comment: In your 2nd function's log, where are you getting the `outputArray` from? Does your 2nd function return something?

Comment: Oops made a slip. The two are equivalent and both return nothing.

Comment: `Array` is `struct` and passed by value in Swift. If you don't use `inout`, you have to return the array in order to receive the change. Without updating the array, every `permutations(n-1, ary)` inside the for-loop basically does nothing before you swap.

Comment: Is it possible to make this algorithm with the signature func permutations (_ n: Int, _ a: Array<Character>) -> [String]

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Sequence-based enumeration of permutations with Heap's algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202994/sequence-based-enumeration-of-permutations-with-heaps-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is `struct` and passed by value in Swift. If you don't use inout, you have to return the array in order to receive the change. Without updating the array, every `permutations(n-1, ary)` inside the for-loop basically does nothing before you swap.

```
func permutations (_ n: Int, _ a: Array<Character>) -> Array<Character> {
    var ary = a
    if (n == 1){
        print(String(ary));
        return ary
    }
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        ary = permutations(n-1, ary)
        ary.swapAt(n-1, (n%2 == 1) ? 0 : i)
    }
    return permutations(n-1, ary)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
func permutations (_ n: Int, _ a: Array<Character>) -> Array<Character> {
    var ary = a
    if (n == 1){
        print(String(ary));
        return ary
    }
    var array = Array<Character>()
    for i in 0..<n-1 {
        array = i == 0 ? permutations(n-1, ary) : permutations(n-1, array)
        array.swapAt(n-1, (n%2 == 1) ? 0 : i)
    }
    return permutations(n-1, array)
}
```